How do I properly implement the Type 2 AC charger vehicle communications ? (IEC 62196 standard)
I'm designing an AC charger for a EV side that uses the Type 2 standard. I dont have the full 62916 spec document but I'm using this as my reference point
So far my design looks like the following

I'm using a relay powered by a transformer-less power supply (TPS) that's powered by the current carrying bus for compact design (the circuit could potentially be fit into a type 2 charging nozzle) and generating less heat
I have a question regarding the switching relay. Should I use an ordinary or latching relay? Any other comments or suggestions?
EDIT: This is the image provided by my source, not sure if I'm implementing it correctly (fair use purposes):

Previously I was using this adapter to charge my vehicle, but I suspect it doesn't implement full comms protocol so it works only on some ESVE:


The relay type does not matter - the coil will never energize. How is that circuit supposed to work?

The 1st resistor is supposed to bring it to 9V to kick start the power then 6V to maintain the supply? Or am I not understanding it correctly?

Using this guide: https://www.picoauto.com/library/automotive-guided-tests/charger-vehicle-communications-type-2

I don't see which resistor you mean, but the relay will not energize, as the transistor never turns on to energize the relay, as the optoisolator LED never gets any power to turn on the transistor, as the relay contacts are open to begin with.

Which resistor is the "1st resistor"? Please label your schematic with component designators like R1, C3, etc. Where would 9V (or 6V) come from?
